# How can i move the screen up when we touch on text field?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can i move(scroll) the screen upwards when i touch a textfield & it should work on ios3 as well as ios4  ( i am developing the app using xcode 4 ) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
// (x,y, width, height) change it as you want   
[yourViewName setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 200.0f, 320.0f, 460.0f)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Good luck.

Comment: actually screen should scroll up on click of a textfield(say its placed at bottom of the screen)so it should scroll up over the keypad

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it, try with a screen shot or with a description of your view hierarchy.

Comment: I would give the view a transform instead of altering its frame